# Apache %{SERVER_NAME} not resolving to ServerName

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have the following VirtualHost in Apache 2.4

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  DocumentRoot /dev/null
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

I expect it to redirect

```
http://www.example.com/ -> https://www.example.com/
http://example.com/ -> https://www.example.com/
```

however, it redirects

```
http://www.example.com/ -> https://www.example.com/
http://example.com/ -> https://example.com/
```

I don't get it... It redirects to the %{HTTP_HOST}. Shouldn't %{SERVER_NAME} be ServerName? Is this the expected behavior, or do I have an error somewhere else? Also, what relevance does the hostname inside the VirtualHost statement have? I haven't found information on that. Thanks.

Comment: [UseCanonicalName On](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname) might help.

Comment: Thx, actually that helps. But I'm not sure if this is the real solution. UseCanonicalName On affects lots of internal processing of the server. In my case, the VHost does nothing else than redirecting, but what is in other cases? I'm still stunned that %{SERVER_NAME} actually contains HTTP_HOST by default.

Comment: you have a serveralias match making it valid as server_name, that's why. If you just wanted to redirect to https www.example.com it is as simple as `Redirect / https://www.example.com/`

Comment: forgot to mention, virtualhost directive is not to be used with hostnames, just with *:port or ip:port.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, as documented at [rewritecond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and 
[usecanonicalname](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname)

```
UseCanonicalName On
```

solves the problem (but has other implications). Whithout that, %{SERVER_NAME} actually contains HTTP_HOST.
If someone knows how to query ServerName with UseCanonicalName Off, please tell me.

Comment: What are the other implications?

Comment: As documentation says, apache will then use ServerName for lots of internal redirects etc. I haven't tested it, but it could be a problem on servers where you generally want to allow access to all aliases. e.g. in my case (without the redirect) accessing `http://example.com/sub/` would return the document from the servers `/sub/index.html` file. However, accessing `http://example.com/sub` would result in an redirect to `http://www.example.com/sub/` . This may e.g. cause sessions to get invalid.